# Promesa y Fetch Reactjs - Mostrar Nombre

Tags: reactjs, promesas, fetch

Por favor necesito mostrar el valor de nombre de esta petición no lo estoy logrando, por favor alguien queme pueda explicar y ayudar que lo que estoy haciendo mal. estoy usando reactjs

Muchas Gracias

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class ListUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nombres: {}
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://freestyle.getsandbox.com/dummy/obtenerdatospersona", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "default"
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ nombres: response });
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

```html
render() {
    console.log(this.state.nombres);
    return (
      
                  <div className="nombre-asegurado">MOSTRAR NOMBRE AQUI</div>
                 
    );
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En consola se muestran los nombres?

Comment: si. sale todo el objeto con los datos, quiero recuperar el valor de nombres. para este caso, entiendo que si quiero obtener mas datos seria lo mismo , no puedo obtener ninguno en el template, en consola si sale revisa el console.log. gracias.

Comment: te subí la imagen de la consola.. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma, además de que así puedes simplificar tu código

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class ListUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nombres: '',
    fechaNacimiento: ''
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    let _fetch = await fetch("https://freestyle.getsandbox.com/dummy/obtenerdatospersona", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "default"
    })
    let json = await _fetch.json()
    let data = json.data.tercero
    this.setState({
      nombres: data.nombres,
      fechaNacimiento: data.fechaNacimiento
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.nombres);
    return (
      <div className="nombre-asegurado">{this.state.nombres}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias, si también carga los datos, la pregunta es me puedas ayudar a colocarlo en el template en el div, me da error cuando lo invoco. <div className="nombre-asegurado">{this.state.nombres}</div>, eso no lo puedo lograr me ayudas, o lo estoy haciendo mal gracias.

Comment: Hola ya esta en la consola ya trae el nombre correcto, solo cuando lo imprimo me sale un error de Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}), hay que pasarle algun id, index, key={nombre}, que peude ser. la respuesta esta correcta solo me pide ese valor

Comment: ya esta solucionado hay que ponerle corchetes en vez de llaves. state = {
    nombres: []
  };

Comment: tambien funciona el string, una pregunta tengo 3 datos asi y funciona state = {
    nombres: "",
    numDocumento: "",
    fecNacimiento: ""
  }; el this.setState({
      nombres: json.data.tercero.nombres,
      numDocumento: json.data.tercero.numDocumento,
      fecNacimiento: json.data.tercero.fecNacimiento
    }); lo tengo asi es correcto o se peude mejorar el setState.

Comment: con ese cambio me dice tercero undefined..

Comment: @SixtoMujica perdón, volví a editar mi respuesta ;)

Comment: Gracias Funciono perfecto no  sabes la ayuda y lección que me has dado, esto no se me olvida, me queda como aprendizaje. muchas gracias por todo.